# pub/sub database schema

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I am having a hard time creating a pub/sub database schema with stateful metrics.

**Saying it aloud it sounds easy enough:**

> "There are many organizations that will subscribe to checklists that
>   are derived from guiding documents for ALL org's. The org's will
>   maintain their own answers for the checklists (T/F), not all org's
>   will need to answer all checklist items. When an author changes a
>   checklist item, the org's should be notified."

**What I have thus far:**
[image]
[ERR.mwb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpdykc4ii87qshn/pub-sub.mwb?dl=0)

**The desired result would be the following:**
Organization #42

- Department
  - Checklist ABC Metrics = 8/10
    - Item Metric = True
    - Item n...
  - Checklist n...
- Department n...

---

**What I am looking for:**

1. Is this architecture close to what I "say" I am looking for?
2. Do pub/sub schemas require many "bridged" tables, as I'ved used?
3. I know updated and created dates would be necessary too but, how do you maintain the state of each department and there answers (Yes/No, True/False) to all of these items within all of the checklists?
4. Is this a Key->Value, Document-Store, Relational, polyglot solution or etc... at its core?
5. I would like to receive any high-level or detailed schemas, links to resources/articles.

Thank you.